# about mysql installation in a LAMP environment

Tags: mysql, lamp

When I build a LAMP environment in ubuntu-12.10,
first I installed mysql by mysql-5.5.12.tar.gz,but it told me that it can not find configure
file,it was here:

```
root@tryandchange-QTH6:/usr/local/src# cd mysql-5.5.12

root@tryandchange-QTH6:/usr/local/src/mysql-5.5.12# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql

bash: ./configure: 没有那个文件或目录(not exists the document or the file)
```

who can tell me why？Or tell me that a good way to build a LAMP environment，
but not 'apt-get install'.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP has downloadable Linux binaries, you just download, extract and run `/path/to/xampp/xampp start` - I'd recommend those as the easiest way to set up a LAMPP stack.

[Link to XAMPP for Linux](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html)

Obviously by eschewing the use of apt, you are working with the knowledge that your apache/php/mysql will become obsolete and you will have to work to keep them secured and up-to-date.